# why change instance variable also changes static variable?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am baffled by the Python behaviour below. Why the attributes of second and third instances (`b`, `c`),  `i`, are the class attribute `i` but `a` behaves differently?

```
In [47]: class Foo:
    ...:     i=0
    ...:

In [48]: a = Foo()

In [49]: a.i = 1

In [50]: a.i
Out[50]: 1

In [51]: Foo.i
Out[51]: 0

In [52]: b = Foo()

In [53]: b.i
Out[53]: 0

In [54]: Foo.i is b.i
Out[54]: True

In [55]: Foo.i is a.i
Out[55]: False

In [56]: c = Foo()

In [57]: Foo.i is c.i
Out[57]: True
```

Comment: Careful with interpreting the results of `int is int`... Python caches small integers. Perhaps it is better to use a dummy class for such demonstrations, although, in this case I don't think it will affect your demonstration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what happens.  When you do:

```
a.i = 1
```

You create an instance variable with a name that *shadows* the class attribute.  The class attribute is still there, though:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     i = 0
...     
>>> a = Foo()
>>> Foo.i
0
>>> a.i = 69
>>> a.i
69
>>> a.__class__.i
0
>>> del a.i  # deletes the instance attribute, resolving lookup on class
>>> a.i
0
```

To see what lives in the instance's namespace, check out the instance dict:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> a.i = 1
>>> a.__dict__
{'i': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.i = 1` does NOT change `Foo.i` as you intended. It rather assigns an instance member of `a`. It is very clear if you see `a.__dict__` and `b.__dict__`.

```
In [11]: a.__dict__
Out[11]: {'i': 1}

In [13]: b.__dict__
Out[13]: {}
```

If you want to really change class member variable, you should use `Foo.i = 1`. That will impact all `Foo` instances. Again, it is very clear on `Foo.__dict__`.

```
In [17]: Foo.__dict__
Out[17]: 
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,
              'i': 0})
```